# To Convert decimal number to hexadecimal with uppercase letters in

Tags: java, string

problem:
Take an integer as input and print the decimal and equivalent hexadecimal values from 1 to that number in 2 columns.
All hexadecimal letters should be in Upper Case.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class DecimalToHexa {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n = 0; 
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a number ");
        n = in.nextInt();
        for(int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + "\t" +  Integer.toHexString(i));
        }

    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Enter a number 14
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   8
9   9
10  a
11  b
12  c
13  d
14  e
```

Please tell me how to convert letters to uppercase.

Comment: use Character.toUpperCase()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use toUpperCase() like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int n = 0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a number ");
    n = in.nextInt();
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + "\t" + Integer.toHexString(i).toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [String#toUpperCase()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase%28%29) method:

```
Integer.toHexString(i).toUpperCase()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int n = 0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a number ");
    n = in.nextInt();
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%d\t%X\n",i,i);
    }
}
```

An alternative way for converting int to hex.

`String s = String.format("%X", num);`

Same rule follows for printf. Formatted printing in java.

You can change capital X to x for lowercase.

Comment: I like this better.  Why generate the string in lower case and then convert it when you can generate it in upper case to begin with?